# Who is Naigamesha, the goat-headed form of Kartikeya?

Tags: scripture, reference-request, kartikeya

In Wikipedia, I learned about a deity named Naigamesha, the goat-headed form of Kartikeya.

But, who is he? Is he mentioned in any scriptures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Naigamesha form of Kartikeya is a personified graha (disease), but he can be appeased with proper prayer.

From [Sushruta Samhita, Uttara Tantra 2.36:](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/sushruta-samhita-volume-6-uttara-tantra/d/doc143035.html)

> Now we shall discourse on the chapter which deals with the medical treatment of (an attack by) Naigamesha...
>
> Offerings of huskless sesamum, garlands of flowers and various dishes should be made to the deity Naigamesha (the preserver of the child) at the foot of a Vata tree on the sixth day of the fortnight and the child should be bathed there at the foot of the tree.
>
> The Mantra runs as follows:—
>
> > “May the far-famed god, Naigamesha, the preserver of children, who has a goat’s face with moving brow and rolling eyes and who can assume different forms at will, preserve the child.”

[Next chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/sushruta-samhita-volume-6-uttara-tantra/d/doc143036.html) (Origins of the grahas) of the same text says:

> The Naigamesha Graha who is possessed of a goat's face was created by the goddess Parvati as the friend and protector of the young god Guha and who was as dear to him as his own self.

A similar reference can be found [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-nilamata-purana/d/doc81740.html), in the Nilamata Purana.

Another text that mentions him as a form of Kartikeya (Skanda) is the [Linga Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-linga-purana/d/doc1196081.html):

> **Lord Skanda will be born** who will sportingly kill the demon Tāraka. **He will be known as** Śaktidhara (holder of Śakti or spear), Ṣaḍāsya (six-faced), Dvādaśabhuja (twelve-armed), Senānī (commander-in-chief), Pāvaki (son of ñre), Svāheya (son of Svāhā), Kārttikeya (son of Kṛttikās), Gāṅgeya (son of Gaṅgā), Śaradhāmaja (born in the abode of the forest Śara, lord Śākha, Viśākha, **Naigameśa**, Senāpati (commander-in-chief), Kumāra, Mahāsena (having a great army). Though he will be only a small boy, he will kill Tāraka and protect Devas.”